# Struts2 prepare method can not be handled

Tags: java, struts2

When I use `implements Preparable` and override `prepare()` method and if I get any problem in preparation I set an action error with `com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport addActionError`.

After prepare method sets the error message I want to process this message in the real initialize method.

```
public class TestClass implements Preparable {

    public void prepare() {
        // ...
        if (error) {
            addActionError("error");
        }
    }

    public String initializeAndDo() {
        String target = ERROR;
        // ...
        return target;
    }

}
```

When I debug it, it never reaches `initiliazeAndDo` method and returns INPUT automatically.

struts.xml : no intercepter in action block.

```
 <action name="action_name" method="initializAndDo" class="TestClass">
    <result name="input">/pages/input.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/pages/error.jsp</result>
 </action>
```

Is there any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure; this is normal behavior.

If there are errors, the `"workflow"` interceptor will see that, and forward to the `"input"` result.

If you don't want to have your (non-standard) workflow interrupted, don't set an error in the `prepare()` method. One alternative would be to set a flag in `prepare()` that could be checked in `initializeAndDo` method--this would keep `"workflow"` from short-circuiting the requst.